# Failed to fetch data for display in dropdwon on dynamic form

Tags: php, loops, dynamic, foreach, dynamicform

I made a dynamic form, there is a dropdown that retrieves data based on the mysql database, in the first part the data appears but when the form is added the data on the dropdwon doesn't appear.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jfb0g.png)

```
<select name="nama[]" id="editable-select1" class="form-control" placeholder="Nama Lengkap">
 <?php
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
  echo '<option value="'.$row["nama"].'">'.$row["nama"].'</option>';
  }
 ?>
</select>
```

I want to make every time the form is added, the dropdown will still display data according to the database

Answer (score 0):

Please provide more information and possible more code to be able to replicate your problem and find a solution, the question is too short and the code provided is not enough.